# How to Call a WebService in titanium using javascript

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-mobile

I am new to titanium and and want to call a web service from my titanium app.
The webService returns the json response.
As I am aware of calling the webService using `XMLRPC` but very confused regarding json.

Until now, I know that we have to create the `HTTPClient`.

```
var request = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
request.open("POST", "http://test.com/services/json");
request.onload = function() {
    var content = JSON.parse(this.responseText);//in the content i have the response data
};

request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //did not understand this line
request.send();
```

Now the problem is if my url(endpoints) have many WebServices, so where i will give the method name i.e WS name which is to be called.

From the API documentation of Titanium mobile the function `open` i.e. `request.open` accepts 3 parameters:

1. method name (http method name)
2. url of request
3. async (boolean property) by default true.

In the above code what is `"POST"` doing there?? and if my WS name is `system.connect` then where i will be mentioning that in code?

And what if the WS needs parameter, so how can we send the parameter to the webService form the above code.

I know that `request.send()` can be used to send parameter but how ??

Comment: Could you give more information about the services you are trying to call? REST or SOAP endpoints?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To invoke a webservice you should:

```
    // create request
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    //set timeout
    xhr.setTimeout(10000);

    //Here you set the webservice address and method
    xhr.open('POST', address + method);

    //set enconding
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    //send request with parameters
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(args));

    // function to deal with errors
    xhr.onerror = function() {

    };

    // function to deal with response
    xhr.onload = function() {
        var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    };
```

**address** is your webservice url.

**method** is the method you desire to invoke.

address+method is a URL, in your example: "http://test.com/services/json" the method invoked would be named json.

**args**: is a json object where it's variable names should have the exact same name as the webservice parameters. You can create a the parameters object like this:

```
var args = {};
args.parameter1 = 'blabla';
args.parameter2 = 'blaaaa';
```

Comment: what you mean by address+method..suppose my address is http://alpha.com/services/json and my method is system.connect so according to you it will be http://alpha.com/services/json + system.connect or http://alpha.com/services/json/system.connect ??

Comment: When i had the + sign, i was concatenating two strings. One with the URL of the webservice endpoint "alpha.com/services/json" and other with the method "system.connect". You can do that or just write the full url: "alpha.com/services/json/system.connect". 

Probably you should test if your webservice is working correctly, you may use fiddler2 to test it.

Comment: well your code got me the idea and finally i managed to make it more usable. I will mark your answer correct..

Comment: xhr.send(); is missing