# Posting JSON to web service using titanium

Tags: java, json, apache, web-services, titanium-mobile

Hi i tried following the answer to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709033/how-to-call-a-webservice-in-titanium-using-javascript)

im trying to post a JSON object to a web service, the web service is a Java Servlet running [here](http://130.206.127.43:8080/Test)

i tried posting to /Test/retrieveData, the method name like the above answer suggested but it did not seem to send.

im still very new to servlets and titanium, is my servlet able to handle this post request, or do i need to create a new servlet?
Thanks for your help

**Titanium Snippet**

```
button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
Ti.API.info('Button Pressed');
var params = {
    Country : textCountry.value,
    Capital : textCapital.value
};

var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({});
xhr.setTimeout(10000);

//set enconding
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

// function to deal with errors
xhr.onerror = function() {
    Ti.API.info('error, HTTP status = ' + this.status);
    alert('Error Sending Data');
};

// function to deal with response
xhr.onload = function() {
    var obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

};

xhr.open("POST", 'http://130.206.127.43:8080/Test/retrieveData');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
```

});

**Java Servlet**

```
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException
{
    JSONObject mainObj  = retrieveData();

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    String output = mainObj.toString();
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    writer.write(output);
    writer.close();
}

private JSONObject retrieveData()
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    json.put("Country", "Ireland");
    json.put("Capital", "Dublin");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Country", "Spain");
    json.put("Capital", "Madrid");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Country","France");
    json.put("Capital", "Paris");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("places", ja);

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException
 {
     JSONObject mainObj  = retrieveData();

     response.setContentType("application/json");
     String output = mainObj.toString();
     PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
     writer.write(output);
     writer.close();
}
```

**Edit**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response)
       throws ServletException, IOException
{
    doGet(request, response);

}
private JSONObject retrieveData()
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

    json.put("Country", "Ireland");
    json.put("Capital", "Dublin");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Country", "Spain");
    json.put("Capital", "Madrid");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    json.put("Country","France");
    json.put("Capital", "Paris");
    ja.put(json);
    json = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject();
    mainObj.put("places", ja);

return mainOBj;
}
```

Comment: could you please add this in onerror console.log(e.error+"-"+this.status)

Comment: yesterday, i added a doPost function into the Java Servlet and there is no longer an error message, the JSON is being sent i just don no how to display it now on the servlet page. Thank you for your comment

Comment: do you now how i can display the JSON object on the servlet page Tony?

Comment: i'm sry i don't know but as i think you just need to convert json object to java object and get it's values then format it as you want in the page